# How to trigger a function when a certain application launches in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, background-process

Assuming a python script running in the background, how can I trigger a function inside the script when I launched a certain application/software on my computer (Linux).

I googled a lot about this, but couldn't find a solution!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Poll the output of `ps aux | grep processname`?

Comment: I am new to Linux and programming, so thanks for commenting. Will try to fetch data using 'grep'. Will update if it works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume, you have to call function callemnow when an external process "abc" has started. There are multiple ways of doing it but below is a sample code which would be easy for you to understand.

> Note: ps -eaf | grep  will give process details. The same command you can call
>   from python script vi subprocess.
>
> while True is just for the convenience. You have to substitute that
>   statement as per your logic flow

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def externalprocess():
    cmd = Popen(['ps', '-eaf'],stdout=PIPE)
    (output, err) = cmd.communicate()
    return True if "abs" in output else False

def callmenow()
    '''
    your logic
    '''

if __name__ == '__main':
    while True:
        if externalprocess():
            callmenow()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! BTW Noticed that you are from Karnataka (same here). :)  

`def checkprocess():
    output=subprocess.check_output("ps -eaf", shell=True).decode('utf-8')
    return True if 'vscode' in output else False`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Can you please accept my code bit as answer? Please give a vote if so. Happy coding!! Good to know that you too Karnataka. :)

Comment: I would love to vote, but i am new to StackOverflow, so my vote doesn't count.